# Serialization of class attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, serialization

Is the default `XmlSerializer` capable of serializing class attributes as Xml attributes?

```
[MyClassTypeAttribute(ClassType.MyClass)]
public MyClass : BaseClass {

}
```

would turn to

```
<myclass MyClassType="MyClass">
```

**Reason**:

I have a WCF service that sends me different objects through the same operation contract which all derive from `BaseClass`. To know which type of object it is and to cast it directly (and serialize it as Xml to write in a document afterwards), I'd like to have some 'type' attribute (`enum`).

One possibility is, of course, declaring a property as `XmlAttribute`

```
[XmlAttribute(params)]
public MyClassType { get; set; }
```

Problem here is: The `XmlSerializer` (`DataContractSerializer` as well, AFAIK) forces me to have a `setter` on every property. I know I can declare the `setter` as `protected` and it still works (*`XmlSerializer`, you naughty little thing*), but don't really like that solution because 1) I think there is a reason that I'm able to leave out the setter in POCOs usually and 2) declaring some properties as `XmlAttributes` and others as `XmlElements` is confusing (it's like putting *dogs* and *cats* into a *cat goulash*.

(Additionally, is it possible to force a derived class to declare certain attributes?)

```
[abstract MyClassTypeAttribute]
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is about the type of your class here is an example:

```
  [XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(ConcreteFooOne))]
  [XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(ConcreteFooTwo))]
  [XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(ConcreteFooThree))]
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooData", Namespace = "http://foo.bar")]
  public abstract partial class AbstractFoo
  {
    // Some abstract props etc.
  }

  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooData", Namespace = "http://foo.bar")]
  public class ConcreteFooOne : AbstractFoo
  {
    public int MyProp { get; set; }
  }
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooData", Namespace = "http://foo.bar")]
  public class ConcreteFooTwo : AbstractFoo
  {

  }
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooData", Namespace = "http://foo.bar")]
  public class ConcreteFooThree : AbstractFoo
  {

  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(AbstractFoo));
      using (var stream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
      {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, new ConcreteFooOne() { MyProp = 10 });
        stream.Flush();
      }


      using (var stream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
      {
        var c = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
      }
    }
  }
```

The code will serialize and include the type attribute and when you deserialize you will get the right instance.